# How to use https in the host header of a post request

Tags: http, post, https, request, host

https://my.example.com works in browser while my.example.com:443 does not, but I need to use the former in a Host Header of a POST request but the Host header can't contain slashes so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: [Read the specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.4).

Comment: Not sure how that helps...

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question. Why does the host header need to contain slashes? In what way doesn't `my.example.com:443` work in your browser?

Comment: If I put my.example.com:443 in my browser I get an error that says "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port", but if I put https://my.example.com it directs me to the correct website. So I want the post request to be directed to that website but the first way doesn't direct to the website, and the second way contains slashes